# Ethernet interface question

Tags: ethernet

Lets say we have an MCU with 10/100Base-T MAC support and we would like to communicate with the 1000Base-X SERDES backplane. How can we do that? Does PHY ICs make an upconversion?

Best.

Comment: Use a chip like the MAX24287

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hello again, I read datasheet of the MAX24287 but on TI e2e forum Ive seen a post like this "MII is not possible for 1000BASE-X/T speeds. MII only supports 10Mbps and 100Mbps.No PHY is capable of supporting MII for 1000BASE-X/T, it is not physically possible." Is it possible or impossible to make connection between an MCU with 10/100Mbps MII to 1000Base-X or TX board?

Answer (score 1):

> It is not possible.
>
> 1000Base-X/FX (SFP module, for example) support only 1Gb Ethernet.
> If you would like to communicate with the 1000Base-X, you should use 1Gb MAC controller that will be connected to PHY controller that support 1000BASE-X SerDes.